# jQuery selector for element of form

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to determine the selector for this form element:

```
   <form action="/php/edit_images_reorder.htm" method="post" name="draglist_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="new_order" value="abc" /> 
   ...
```

This is what I'm working with right now:

```
$("form > [name='new_order']").val(...)
```

I want to assign a value to this form element from a function. Anyone know what the correct selector is? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just tested it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/H2D8x/1/

```
$("form [name=new_order]").val("my value");
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct selector. Too short.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track:

```
$('form input[name="new_order"]').val('This is the new value');
```

What wasn't working in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("form input[name='new_order']").val(...)
```

Or you could give it an id? easier and more performant.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
$('input[name="new_order"]').val('newval');
```

But what you have should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What's your actual problem?  The selector appears correct to me:

See http://jsfiddle.net/AP8VA/1/

I would note for consistency that you should have the quote marks the other way around - use double quotes to represent the attribute and single quotes to demarcate the Javascript string.

This is a better fit for HTML which strictly speaking should have double quotes around attributes.